# How to display two series via Google Chart API?

Tags: line, charts, series

I can't get the two series of numbers to scale together.

Here is sample code that you can paste into...
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/docs/chart_playground.html

```
cht=lxy
chs=400x300
chd=t:20,30,40|1,4,2|24,34,44|3,7,1
chds=20,40,1,4,24,44,1,7
chxr=0,20,54,2|1,0,7,1
chxt=x,y
chxs=0,ff0000,12,0,lt
    1,0000ff,10,1,lt
chco=FF0000,00FF00
chdl=Apples
    Oranges
chtt=Some+Values
chts=0000ff,24
```

Translated:

```
chd=t:s,e,r,i,e,s,1|s,e,r,i,e,s,2|...ors:series1,series2,...ore:series1,series2,...
chds=<series_1_min>,<series_1_max>,...
chxr=<axis_index>,<start_val>,<end_val>,<step>|...
```

The three varying parameters in question are:
    chd=t:20,30,40|1,4,2|24,34,44|3,7,1
    chds=20,40,1,4,24,44,1,7
    chxr=0,20,54,2|1,0,7,1

Can anyone get this simple example working?

The chart supports multiple series but for some reason I can't scale it so that the values are displayed within scale.

Any help appreciated,
Chris

Comment: It appears that I may need to do a couple things... 1. Normalize the data to fit within a 0-100 scale.  2. Balance the data series such that they contain an equal # of values for both series, using a 0 or -1 to display null values.

Answer (score 3):

After some practice I think I needed to make the chds values the same for both sets of data.  I need to play with it more but I thought I would post a working example for posterity.

```
cht=lxy
chs=400x300
chd=t:20,30,40|1,4,2|24,34,44,48|3,7,1,2
chds=10,50,0,10,10,50,0,10
chxr=0,10,50|1,0,10,1
chxt=x,y
chxs=0,ff0000,12,0,lt
    1,0000ff,10,1,lt
chco=FF0000,00FF00
chdl=Apples
     Oranges
chtt=Some+Values
chts=0000ff,24
chm=o,0000FF,0,-1,5,0|o,ff0000,1,-1,5,0
chg=10,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Scaling can be tricky to get right.
Try using chds='a' for automatic scaling at first.